# First Table select jumps across screen once option is chosen

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to create a table to have certain rows appear when different reports are chosen. When a report is chosen though, the first select gets pushed across the screen to the right side. Will someone please tell me what is causing this?

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><p>Please select a report:</p></td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control" id="reporttype" name="reporttype"> 
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Report</option>
                <option id ="checklistreports" value="checklistreports" >Checklist Stats</option>
                <option id ="locationreports" value="locationreports" >Location Stats</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="location" style="display: none;">
            <select name="Location" id="loc" multiple="multiple" required size="9">
                <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
                <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
                <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
                <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
                <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
                <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
                <option value="NR">North River</option>
                <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
                <option value="FSC">FSC</option>
            </select>

            <button id="add" type="button">ADD ALL</button>
            <button id="rem" type="button">REMOVE ALL</button>

            <textarea id="selected" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="employeelist" style="display: none;">
            <cfquery name="GetActiveEmps" datasource="tco_associates">
                SELECT assoc_userid, assoc_last, assoc_first FROM tco_associates
                WHERE assoc_status = 'ACTIVE' 
                and assoc_last NOT LIKE 'Test%' 
                and len(assoc_last) > 0 
                ORDER BY assoc_last
            </cfquery>    

            <select name="EmployeeName" id="EmployeeName" multiple="multiple" required size="9">
                <cfoutput query="GetActiveEmps">
                    <option value="#assoc_userid#">#Trim(assoc_last)#, #Trim(assoc_first)#</option>
                </cfoutput>
            </select>

            <button id="add1" type="button">ADD ALL</button>
            <button id="rem1" type="button">REMOVE ALL</button>

            <textarea id="selected1" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="chosendates" style="display: none;">
            <label for="StartDate">From</label>
            <input type='text' name="StartDate" id="StartDate" value="" required/>

            <label for="EndDate">To</label>
            <input type='text' name="EndDate" id="EndDate" value="" required/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="formattype" style="display: none;">
            <label for="Format">Format</label>
            <select name="Format" required>
                <option selected value="">Select Format</option>
                <option value="print">Print</option>
                <option value="pdf">Preview</option>
                <option value="xls">Excel</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="submitbtn" style="display: none;">
            <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Continue" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).on('change', '#reporttype', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();

        //var checklistreport = $("#checklistreport");
        //var locationreport = $("#locationreport");
        var location = $("#location");
        var employeelist = $("#employeelist");
        var chosendates = $("#chosendates");
        var formattype = $("#formattype");
        var submitbtn = $("#submitbtn");

        if (value == "checklistreports") {
            //checklistreport.show();
            //locationreport.hide();
            location.show();
            employeelist.show();
            chosendates.show();
            formattype.show();
            submitbtn.show();
        } else if (value == "locationreports") {
            //checklistreport.hide();
            //locationreport.show();
            location.show();
            employeelist.hide();
            chosendates.show();
            formattype.show();
            submitbtn.show();
        } else {
            //checklistreport.hide();
            //locationreport.hide();
            location.hide();
            employeelist.hide();
            chosendates.hide();
            formattype.hide();
            submitbtn.hide();
        }
    });
</script>

<!--<div id="locationreport" style="display: none;">-->
<form name="generatereport" method="post" action="_location_queries.cfm">
<!--<div id="checklistreport" style="display: none;">-->
<form name="generatereport" method="post" action="_checklists_queries.cfm">

</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
// JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea
var opts = document.querySelectorAll('#loc option');

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        opts[i].selected = true;
    }

    reflectChange();
});

document.getElementById('rem').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        opts[i].selected = false;
    }

    reflectChange();
});

document.getElementById('loc').addEventListener('change', reflectChange);

function reflectChange() {
    document.getElementById('selected').value = '';

    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        if(opts[i].selected)
        document.getElementById('selected').value += opts[i].text+'\n';
    }
}

// End JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea

// JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea
var opts1 = document.querySelectorAll('#EmployeeName option');

document.getElementById('add1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts1.length; i++ ) {
        opts1[i].selected = true;
    }

    reflectChange1();
});

document.getElementById('rem1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts1.length; i++ ) {
        opts1[i].selected = false;
    }

    reflectChange1();
});

document.getElementById('EmployeeName').addEventListener('change', reflectChange1);

function reflectChange1() {
    document.getElementById('selected1').value = '';

    for ( var i=0; i<opts1.length; i++ ) {
        if(opts1[i].selected)
        document.getElementById('selected1').value += opts1[i].text+'\n';
    }
}

// End JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea
   </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/o2gxgz9r/10040/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because the select list used to choose the report is in the second table cell of the first row, and when the contents in the subsequent table rows are displayed, the width of the first column is increased, which in turn pushes the second column off to the right. An illustration of this is in the screenshot below.

One approach to avoid having the select list not pushed to the right side is to use the [colspan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan) attribute to the subsequent rows (i.e. add `colspan="2"`), or perhaps move the select list into the first column and use CSS to have it aligned to the right side (e.g. with [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)).

[image: table cells outlined]